# How to manage GUI interaction with an OO JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop, user-interface

There is a time table in my web page, I want the user to be able to:

- click on a cell and see which courses is at this time
- click on an arrow and change de week

How should I build my JavaScript classes?

1. I don't use classes and I interact with the dom as we can see in 99% of the JavaScript code in the world
2. I create one class TimeTable that will observe event (such as click on a cell), make ajaxcall, change the cell content etc...
3. I try to make things perfect:

   - A) a class that will wrap all the html stuff (changing style/ content)
   - B) a class that will wrap my ajax call
   - C) a class that will wrap my business logic
   - D) a class to make all those things work together, observe the event from An and call C or D and then call A to change the UI.

IMHO the last solution is the best it's kind of a MVC (An is the View, D is the Controller, and the two others are the models). But it seems like one of the less easy to implement.

Did you ever use this kind of technique? Is there any related blog / documentation to help me? Do you think it's relevant? There is something better?

Comment: What are you using on the backend? Also, do you have a good understanding of how MVC works - particularly in the context of web applications? If not, I would recommend finding a tutorial for your particular solution (for example, NerdDinner for ASP.NET MVC) and do some reading to make sure you have a solid grasp of the fundamentals.

Comment: @JasCav Why does it matters what is the backend ? It's only a client-side problem, both are totally independent.

Comment: Perhaps I didn't understand your question. (I specifically thought you were looking for an solution utilizing the MVC paradigm which would require work on the backend as well.)

Comment: @JasCav You can implement MVC in the backend and/or in the front end (http://www.codethinked.com/building-epic-win-with-backbone-js) , no ?

Comment: @JasCav @remibourgarel MVC works fine in the front end. It's actually pretty powerful. The only thing you need the back end is for security, you never trust clients ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [backbonejs](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/). It's light weight MVC with full control over the view and html system.

The design decisions of the application structure are varied and really should be upto you if you want to achieve your own functionality.

Comment: @Raymos I looked at it but it seems like a revolution compared to what I wanted to do : 1/ REST instead of ajax (I'm not against it, I just want to learn thing one after the other) 2/ this whole activerecord model is really disturbing when you begin.

Comment: @remibourgarel active record? not sure what you mean. Backbone comes with REST by default. The entire data driven part of backbone is modularized so you can just overwrite `Backbone.sync` to talk to the database over ajax instead. Give me some more details about how you want to structure your MVC and I'll mock up a solution.

Comment: activerecord is a bit like a orm work : you fill like you're saving directly your object in the data store (here the web server) so you don't call directly your datalayer, the framework knows when it has to call the crud methods. My srtucture is like I said in the topic : a timetable with the week courses (as the view), the week courses with their attendance (the model), the ajax call for the data and a controller that take all this and mix them ^^ is it clear ?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use [jQuery FullCalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/)?

[image: fullcalendar screenshot]

If instead you really want to write the whole thing yourself, I'd recommend [JavaScriptMVC](http://javascriptmvc.com/).

Comment: jQuery FullCalendar is suprisingly polished.

Comment: I'm not looking for a nice control, I'm just asking what would be the best practice if I want to do something good.But thanks

Comment: @remi: then see the bit about JS MVC.

Comment: I had a look, I think it's more appropriate for a big javascript application, no ?